# How to add some text from helper to system config

Tags: magento2

I want to add module current version to system config.

in helper i am getting module version and show it to system config

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleListInterface` to achieve this.

First, **update your helper** (add `ModuleListInterface` and `getModuleVersion` method):

```
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleListInterface */
protected $moduleListInterface;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleListInterface $moduleListInterface
)
{
    $this->moduleListInterface = $moduleListInterface;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function getModuleVersion()
{
    $data = $this->moduleListInterface->getOne('Vendor_Module');
    if (isset($data['setup_version'])) {
        $version = $data['setup_version'];
    } else {
        $version = null; // unknown
    }

    return $version; // string like "2.0.0"
}
```

**Create frontend model** for the element in config - `Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Forms\Renderer\Config\Version.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Forms\Renderer\Config;

use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement;
use Vendor\Module\Helper\Data as Helper;

class Version extends Field
{
    protected $helper;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        Helper $helper,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->helper = $helper;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @param AbstractElement $element
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getElementHtml(AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $element->setStyle('width:70px;')->setName($element->getName() . '[]');

        // Return html here
        return __(
            '<label class="label"><span>' . $this->helper->getModuleVersion() . '</span></label>'
        );
    }
}
```

**Add field to the config** (inside `config > system > section > group` in file `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/system.xml`):

```
<field id="module_ver" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Module version</label>
    <frontend_model>Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Forms\Renderer\Config\Version</frontend_model>
</field>
```

**Result** (test):

[image: result]

#### Old answer:

> Do something like this in the helper code:
>
> ```
> /** @var \Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleListInterface */
> protected $moduleListInterface;
>
> public function __construct(
>     \Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleListInterface $moduleListInterface
> )
> {
>     $this->moduleListInterface = $moduleListInterface;
> }
>
> public function getModuleVersion()
> {
>     $data = $this->moduleListInterface->getOne('VendorName_ModuleName');
>     if (isset($data['setup_version']) {
>         $version = $data['setup_version'];
>     } else {
>         $version = null; // unknown
>     }
>
>     return $version; // string like "2.0.0"
> }
> ```
>
> [image: Data for magento catalog]

PS: do not forget to change `VendorName_ModuleName` to the real vendor name and module name (**case sensitive**)

Comment: And how can i show it to system config?

Comment: @Newbie I've updated my answer. Tested, it works.

Comment: ModuleListInterface will through error while `setup:di:compile` command run

Comment: @SCC Which error? Could you add it in comment?

Comment: When i am using `\Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleListInterface $moduleListInterface`  in code it will throw an error while compiling the code

Comment: Error is:  ` [ReflectionException]
  Class ModuleListInterface does not exist` And magento version is `Magento2.1.8`

Comment: @SCC It's strange, because this class is exists in the 2.1.8 https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1.8/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/ModuleListInterface.php